# automation/v1/filetransfers - patch endpoint not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

For a specific usecase, I need to do dynamic csv exports from SFMC to an external serveur (s3).
the dataextract works well. I can browse a list of DE, modify 1 temporary dataextract activity (by changing the fileSpec via REST from the endpoint `{{restEndPoint}}/automation/v1/dataextracts/{DataExtractKey}`).

However, trying to do the same with the FileTransferActivity, it is impossible to modify an attribute of the object :(

Even I have selected all the fields

```
url=> {{restEndPoint}}/automation/v1/filetransfers/{fileTransfer_ObjectID} 
paylod => {"description":"Update FileTransfer to S3 for AUDIENCE_123","fileSpec":"AUDIENCE_123.csv"}
```

The endpoint Discovery on Automation explains that the update is available:

```
"FileTransfer.Update": {       
    "path": "filetransfers/{FileTransferId}",       
    "httpMethod": "patch",       
    "description": "Update File Transfer Collection",       
    "parameters": {}     
},
```

Questions:
Are there any mandatory fields, like "dataExtractTypeId" for the "DataExtracts - PATCH"?
if yes, which ones?

Script to perform the update (REST):

```
var restapi_url = rest_conf.restEndpoint + "/automation/v1/filetransfers/" + fileTA_ObjectID;
var contentType = "application/json";
var sendMethod = "PATCH";

var restapi_payload = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{'
                +'"description": "Update FileTransfer to S3 for...'+ objN +'",'
                +'"fileSpec": "' + objN + '.csv",'
+'}');

var accToken = requestToken();
var accessToken = accToken.token;

var url = restapi_url;
var payload = Stringify(restapi_payload);
var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
req.retries = 1;
req.continueOnError = true;
req.contentType = "application/json"
req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
req.method = sendMethod;
req.postData = payload;

var resp = req.send();

var resultString = String(resp.content);
```

can you tell me how to change the filename of the "transferActivity" in REST?

Result when a submit the request (PATCH) on FileTransfers (Note that the FileTransferActivity is never Updated :-(

```
  Send call result>
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "name": "FT_EXPORT_IN_S3",
    "description": "Update FileTransfer to S3 for...AUDIENCE_123",
    "customerKey": "e7428440-f365-44f6-88df-e16fd0edc92b",
    "fileSpec": "AUDIENCE_123.csv",
    "isEncrypted": false,
    "isCompressed": false,
    "maxFileAge": 0,
    "maxFileAgeScheduleOffset": 0,
    "maxImportFrequency": 0,
    "fileTransferLocationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "isUpload": true,
    "isPgp": false,
    "isFileSpecLocalized": true,
    "createdDate": "2021-09-30T22:30:31.403",
    "modifiedDate": "2021-10-14T20:27:17.983"
} 

Debut transfert: Result transfert: 
{
    "Status": "OK",
    "StatusMessage": "",
    "RequestID": "b804415d-4eec-4806-aefd-db75ec209e74",
    "Results": [
        {
            "Object": {
                "InteractionObjectID": null,
                "Name": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Keyword": null,
                "Client": null,
                "PartnerKey": null,
                "PartnerProperties": null,
                "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000",
                "ModifiedDate": null,
                "ID": 0,
                "ObjectID": "01924735-735c-4403-a424-6bffcfe6c77d",
                "CustomerKey": null,
                "Owner": null,
                "CorrelationID": null,
                "ObjectState": null,
                "IsPlatformObject": false
            },
            "Task": {
                "StatusCode": "OK",
                "StatusMessage": "OK",
                "OrdinalID": 0,
                "ErrorCode": 0,
                "ID": "1489931",
                "TblAsyncID": 1489931,
                "InteractionObjectID": "bfd1e22e-b42c-46cf-a18c-4ac192375f59"
            },
            "ProgramActivityInstanceId": null,
            "StatusCode": "OK",
            "StatusMessage": "FileTransferActivity performed AsyncID:1489931",
            "OrdinalID": 0,
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "RequestID": null,
            "ConversationID": null,
            "OverallStatusCode": null,
            "RequestType": "Synchronous",
            "ResultType": null,
            "ResultDetailXML": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So from my tests inside of POSTman, the only requirement outside of having the id inside of the endpoint is to include the "fileTransferLocationId" inside of the payload. I am not positive why this is required, but the call returns an 'internal server error' (500) status any time it is not present.

The easiest way to get this information is to do a GET on the id:

```
GET /automation/v1/filetransfers/{{fileTransferId}}
Host: {{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

This then returns a full detailed JSON of all the related information, including fileTransferLocationId.

I would then push this into the PATCH call along with the information you need to change. Something like:

```
PATCH /automation/v1/filetransfers/{{fileTransferId}}
Host: {{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "fileTransferLocationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "description": "my description",
    "fileSpec": "myFile.csv"
}
```

This should have your call be successful and make the appropriate adjustments. I have tested successfully from POSTman as well as from a SSJS call in a CloudPage.

Comment: Hi @Gortoningtin,
Thanks for yr answer.
Yes, i tried this (add the fileTransferLocationId that i retrieve as you mentionned via a GET)

Result: when i include this fileTransferLocationId in the payload and submit the request PATCH, i receive a 200 OK response.
right after, calling the get endpoint, no fields are update after the call :-(

It seems that, in the backend, the request is received without any action
Were you able to verify that the fields were updated after the request (postman + SSJS cloudpage)?

Comment: @joe_le_rap - yes, my fields were changed accordingly with the 200 response both in UI and in the second GET response in POSTman.