# Import lots of files from ftp to update datas extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automation, data-import, sftp

I need to import 81 one different files daily, from a sftp, at a especific time, and overwrite the respectives data extensions. How do I do that without building 81 automations? How do I use ssjs to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Script Activity to update the file name on Import and File Transfer Activities.  If you have a list of the file specs in a DE, you can use a single Automation.

Updating the File Transfer activities is a REST API PATCH operation:

`PATCH /automation/v1/filetransfers/{{FileTransferObjectID}}`

Example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/360039/5202

Updating the ImportDefinition is a SOAP API operation, which you can do with WSProxy in SSJS.

Structure of that object is like this:

```javascript
var importDefinition = {

       "Name": importName,
       "CustomerKey": importName,
       "Description": importName,
       "AllowErrors": "true",
       "DestinationObject": {
              "__Type__": "DataExtension",
              "CustomerKey": targetDEKey
       },
       "FieldMappingType": "InferFromColumnHeadings",
       "FileSpec": fileName,
       "FileType": "CSV",
       "Notification": {
              "ResponseType": "email",
              "ResponseAddress": notificationEmail
        },
       "UpdateType": "AddAndUpdate",
       "RetrieveFileTransferLocation": {
              "CustomerKey": "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP - Import"
       }
};
```

An automation like this is not for the faint of heart.